# Face recognition in Hybrid apps: Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a Hybrid app using apache Cordova where I would like to integrate a face recognition API, preferably https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api.
Is there any way I can integrate the API in my Cordova project. Also, other suggestions regarding some other face recognition APIs would be great.
Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out these link,

https://www.ezartech.com/blog/2016/9/16/ezar-adds-face-detection-for-cordova

https://catchoom.com/documentation/on-device-image-recognition-sdk/cordova-on-device-image-recognition-plugin/

Comment: What about the Microsoft Cognitive Services? Can I integrate that in Cordova?