# Face ID authentication for ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there any API for Face Id authentication in Ionic 1. We need for iOS and android. Is there any existing pluggin supporting both the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recently plugin update from EddyVerbruggen has it. Check the plugin [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id) but it only supports ios.  You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625050/859968) answer that might help you.